# Is there a way to execute compiled C code from inside a bash script?

Tags: c, bash, gcc

Essentially, I wish to call compiled C code from inside a bash script. I want to be able to call the ./a.out from any directory and have it be executed.

This all stems from something pretty simple. I made a curses program that is a screensaver for a terminal. I wish to be able to call a bash command `screensaver` and I want that to call the c code via bash. I want to be able to call it from anywhere in the filesystem. I am running on a 2013 Macbook but I think this is more of an infamiliarity with C issue rather than a hardware issue, I can provide more details if needed.

File is here:

`/Users/User/screensaver/screensaver.c`

`cd /Users/User/screensaver`

`gcc screensaver.c` creates `a.out`

I can then run

`./a.out`
And the code runs.

I have tried calling `./Users/User/screensaver/a.out` among other things.

This doesn't work and it just says that the file doesn't exist. I've tried using `exec` and `source` but nothing has worked. Surely there must be a way to call this from somewhere else right? I know I could theoretically save my current directory as an environment variable, `cd` into the dir, `./a.out`, then on quit `cd` back into the saved dir, but that seems like to much struggle for what its worth.

Edit: I saw that I could theoretically put it in the my `bin` and compiled with `-o`. I haven't tried it, but I don't want to do that because this code is still in development so I don't want to have to compiled and move it every time.

Comment: You just need to put /Users/User/screensaver in your PATH

Comment: Try to invoke `/Users/User/screensaver/a.out` *without* putting a dot at the beginning of the path. There is a paticular security reason why you need to specify `./a.out` rather than `a.out` when you are in the directory which holds the executable.

Comment: Stick the binary in your path or use an absolute path to it.

Comment: Why do you want to invoke it from a bash script instead of just invoking the compiled binary directly?  As others noted, if you want to be able to invoke your binary from anywhere, you need to add its location to your `PATH` environment variable or you need to move the binary to an existing directory from `PATH`.  Also, I would suggest renaming it something other than `a.out`.

Comment: Better yet, create a symlink to `a.out` (of course renamed to a sane name) in `/usr/local/bin` -- which should be in the default search path of most all distros. (you will have to check on Mac, I have no way to do it, but I suspect it is there). You may need superuser to do `ln -s /path/to/a.out /usr/local/bin/`. Further the `-o` option simply tells the compiler to output the compiled code to the name following `-o` (instead of the default `a.out`). So `gcc -o screensaver screensaver.c` (will create the executable `screensaver` rather than `a.out`)

Comment: A critical detail.  An 'executable' can not be simply executed by giving a path to it without first calling `chmod()` to make the 'executable' to be actually executable

Comment: suggest 'brushing up' on 'absolute paths' and 'relative paths'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

"Try to invoke /Users/User/screensaver/a.out without putting a dot at the beginning of the path. There is a paticular security reason why you need to specify ./a.out rather than a.out when you are in the directory which holds the executable."
-tshiono

Comment: The `PATH` environment variable tells the shell the various locations to look  for a program to execute, if you don't specify a path for the program.  So, you could add `/Users/User/sceensaver` to `PATH`.  Alternately, you can specify a path.  Invoking `/Users/User/screensaver/a.out` is a full path, whereas `./a.out` indicates to run `a.out` in the current directory.  `./Users/Users/screensaver/a.out` means to locate the file by digging down starting with the current directory, rather than from the filesystem root (`/`), which is not what you want in this case.

Comment: @Perette So are you saying there are performance benefits to adding to the ```PATH``` rather than calling it from ```/Users/User/screensaver```?

Comment: Making `PATH` longer will actually slow things down, since there's more places for the shell to search when you run something without a path.  The upside is convenience of being able to run your executable without having to worry about its path.